# Running Intel's VTune Periodically

Tags: windows, intel, performancecounter, intel-vtune

In previous versions of VTune, there was a program called dsep.exe, which could be used to periodically poll hardware counters (specifically related to DRAM reads/writes) from VTune. This allowed me to gather counter data about each instance in time, rather than one summary at the end.

Unfortunately, this tool has been deprecated in 64-bit operating systems. Does anyone know a way to periodically (e.g., every 1 sec) get hardware counter data from VTune (or another program in Windows)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I realized I should have been a bit more explicit. It's very possible to do a user-mode sampling which runs periodically, but it's only a subset of all of the available counters, and only runs on one process. I need to (if possible) periodically sample the hardware-based counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, I wasn't able to completely fix this issue, but I got pretty close.

The latest version of VTune saves all of the hardware counter data in a SQLite database (projectfolder/sqlite-db/dicer.db). Since you can't get all of the hardware counter data exported directly from the GUI, you can use a SQLite browser data to get to the data you need.

Most of the hardware data is stored in the pmu-data table, timestampped with some wonky version of a rdtsc call.